# JUnit5 Console Launcher not finding tests

Tags: junit5

I've seen a number of posts on this, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

The problem is that the JUnit5 console launcher cannot seem to find my tests, regardless of syntax that I try.  I've tried scanning for them with --scan-classpath and specifying the class directly with -c, including the package specifier, which generates a NoClassDefFound.

With --scan-classpath the console launcher runs successfully, but doesn't include any unit test executions - doesn't find the test classes for some reason.

The tree looks like this:

```
junit-5-jars  (the console standalone jar is in here) 
src   
   mypackage
     MyClass.java
     MyClass.class 
test   
   mypackage
     MyClassShould.java
     MyClassShould.class
```

From the root of that, the first and most basic command I tried:

`java -jar junit5-jars/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.0-all.jar --class-path=test --class-path=src --scan-classpath`

All variations I've tried give me:

```
Test run finished after 27 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

This is on a Mac from bash.  In a project with all class files at the root of where I'm running the command, I can run tests with the console launcher successfully.  But if class files are in subdirectories like this, no go.  Anyone have ideas? (Note - see answer below, subdirectories were not the issue - the "Should" in the test class name was).

Comment: Have you tried without „mypackage“ suffix? Moreover „-classpath“ is spelled without dash in the middle if I remember correctly. And finally the two classpath components should be separated by a semicolon.

Comment: Yep - it's buried in the text there, but I have tried to drop the mypackage and just use --class-path test.  I think that's actually the right way - packages aren't included in classpath entries.  But same results - doesn't find the test.  According to JUnit5 ConsoleLauncher documentation, -cp, --classpath, and --class-path are all acceptable (and I've tried all three of them).  Remember this is the classpath argument being passed to the ConsoleLauncher, rather than the java command itself.  Their docs are here:  https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

Answer (score 2):

I think I've discovered the source of this problem - it was the "Should" in the test class name, which JUnit5 ConsoleLauncher does not include to be scanned by default.

This works:

```
java -jar junit5-jars/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.0-all.jar --class-path=test:src --include-classname=.* --scan-classpath
```

The include classname option takes a regex, but in my case I just let it scan all the files on the classpath for tests, and it finds them as it should.

Would be helpful if the --scan-classpath description in their docs referenced the include-classname option and/or their default scanning inclusions.  Easy to miss that argument in that wall of options.

Comment: You can change the default classpath pattern if you want to. The reason there is a pattern at all is due to the fact that classpath scanning is a very expensive operation. Being able to filter out most classes by name is THE performance booster when you deal with thousands and thousands of classes.

Comment: Yes,I see that now in the "-include-classname=PATTERN" argument.  Some statement at the top of their Launcher docs or in the description of the "scan-classpath" argument as to what the default is and how to change it would have saved me some time.  I was just expecting it to work roughly like IDEs, Maven, and Gradle I believe generally do, which is not to base discovery of tests on test class names but rather the annotations and/or directory conventions.

Comment: At least in Gradle you’ll see the same behaviour, without changing the default patterns a test ending on Should is not being executed.